# Generate user interface from tooltip specified as string

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say I have specified a `ToolTip` like this in my XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="Smurf">
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <TextBlock Text="Muppet" />
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

From code behind, I can retrieve this `ToolTip` like this:

```
var tooltip = textBlock.ToolTip as ToolTip;
```

Now, say that I specify the `ToolTip` directly on the `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Text="Smurf" ToolTip="Muppet" />
```

When I retrieve the `ToolTip` the same way, tooltip is `null` because it is a `string`.

**Question:** How do I convert this `string` into a `ToolTip`?

What I'm looing for is a sibling to `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem()` that converts objects into a user interface item for `ItemsControls`.

**Update:**

I believe I have found the corresponding WPF code, in `PopupControlService`... unfortunately, not very reusable:

```
private void RaiseToolTipOpeningEvent()
{
    // ...

    object tooltip = ToolTipService.GetToolTip(o);
    ToolTip tip = tooltip as ToolTip;
    if (tip != null)
    {
        _currentToolTip = tip;
        _ownToolTip = false;
    }
    else if ((_currentToolTip == null) || !_ownToolTip)
    {
        _currentToolTip = new ToolTip();
        _ownToolTip = true;
        _currentToolTip.SetValue(ServiceOwnedProperty, BooleanBoxes.TrueBox);

        // Bind the content of the tooltip to the ToolTip attached property
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty);
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        binding.Source = o;
        _currentToolTip.SetBinding(ToolTip.ContentProperty, binding);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a String to a Tooltip , what you can do is create a new Tooltip in code behind and set the content like this,

```
 string str = ((TextBlock)sender).ToolTip.ToString();
 ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
 tip.Content = str;
```

Comment: If I do it this way, the `ToolTip` instance won't include the style/template. I was hoping that WPF exposes a method for creating the `ToolTip`, just like `ItemContainerGenerator` does for `ItemsControls`.

Comment: @TorbjörnKalin You can apply the style from here as well